# Robospice upload files issue

Tags: android, robospice

I am newbie with [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice).
I am trying to upload files. But I got this error :

```
 04-02 17:47:31.151: E//RequestProcessor.java:234(11021): org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.lang.String] and content type [text/html]
```

.This is my request class :

```
public class UploadFileRequest extends SpringAndroidSpiceRequest<String>{
private static final String TAG = "UploadFileRequest";
private UploadRequestModel requestModel;
private String link;

public UploadFileRequest(UploadRequestModel model, String link) {
    super(String.class);
    requestModel = model;
    this.link = link;
}

@Override
public String loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {    


    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    parts.add("file1", new FileSystemResource(requestModel.getFile1()));
    parts.add("file2", new FileSystemResource(requestModel.getFile1()));
    return getRestTemplate().postForObject(link, parts, String.class);


}

}
```

I am working with : JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService class.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Oooh yeah... got tons of these even with GET requests... You know what I ended up doing ? Not using Spring templates... Oh, and sub-classing  SpringAndroidSpiceService. And no, I have no f*** idea what the hell was wrong. Idiotic frameworks...

Comment: Yes. I see it is quite complex. But I believe it is gonna be useful for my project :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the `JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService` [source code](http://bit.ly/14KFBTJ), it provides a converter for `application/json` content-type only, through the `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` class.

For any other content-type Spring doesn't know how to handle it.

You can easily add a general pourpose converter with the `StringHttpMessageConverter` class subclassing `JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService` or creating your own implementation base on its source code.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved it with the following

replace

```
return getRestTemplate().postForObject(link, parts, String.class);
```

with

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
return restTemplate.postForObject(link, parts, String.class);
```

Hope this helps!